# Using Graph API : Could application information grabbed with api()?

Tags: php, facebook

I can get the user info with this code:

```
$uid = $facebook ->getUser();
$me = $facebook ->api('/me');
```

And App'id:

```
$appId = $facebook->getAppId();
```

How can I make a query from  [application table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application)  (like $facebook ->api('/me')).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace "me" with the application ID. For example,

```
$facebook->api('/2439131959/feed');
```

Comment: Qiang; There is an error : "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#15) The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session thrown in"